# JavaScript que me permita darle a submit en condiciones determinadas

Tags: javascript

Busco un JavaScript que me permita enviar el formulario solo si la fecha y hora seleccionada en datetimepicker sea posterior a la fecha y hora actual y el formulario esté vacío o que el formulario esté relleno y datetimepicker vacío.
Gracias!

```html
<section class="contenedor4">
    <div class="container-fluid f-white">

      <div class="row">

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                
                <ul class="puntos-encuesta pregunta">
                                   
                <p class="rojo planes"> Reprogramar agenda</p>
                <br>
                                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                  
                 <h3 class="muchas-gracias-cc">&iexcl;Muchas gracias por tu opini&oacute;n!</h3>

                <input class="boton-rojo-cc enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">
             
             
             
             

                </ul>

            </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </section>



 <script>
        $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker();
    </script>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head><!-- StartFormCustomCSS -->
    <style type="text/css">

    .algo-mas{
    width: 130%
  }
    .muchas-gracias{
     width: 140% 
  }
    .boton-rojo{
      margin: 20px 355px auto
  }
    .algo-mas-cc{
        width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px;
    font-family: 'CO-Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    }

    .muchas-gracias-cc{
      font-family: 'CO-Bold';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    color: #646464;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    .boton-rojo-cc{
      display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
    height: auto;
    background-color: #DC0028;
    width: 255px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'CO-Bold';
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 12px 0 12px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: none;
    }




</style>

   <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Auto</title>
  <!-- core CSS -->


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery.datetimepicker2.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="prettify-1.0.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="jquery.boostrap-datatimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker2.full.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.boostrap-datatimepicker.js"></script>


</head>

<body id="home" class="homepage">

<section class="cabecera">

<span elqid="38" elqtype="DynamicContent" class="remove-absolute" style="display: block"></span>

</section>

       <form name="EncuestaCallCenter" class="formulario" id="form63" onsubmit="return handleFormSubmit(this)" method="post" autocomplete="off">



<section class="contenedor2"><input name="lang" id="lang" value="ES" type="hidden" value="ES"/>
    <div class="container-fluid f-white">

      <div class="row">

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                <p class="rojo planes"> 1.¿Cómo se llama su mascota?.</p>
                <br>

                <ul class="puntos-encuesta pregunta">
                                    <textarea class="algo-mas-cc" name="PCC1" maxlength="250" id="fe589"></textarea>

                </ul>

            </div>


      </div>

    </div>
</section>

<section class="contenedor2"><input name="lang" id="lang" value="ES" type="hidden" value="ES"/>
    <div class="container-fluid f-white">

      <div class="row">

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                <p class="rojo planes"> 2. ¿Cómo se llama su otra mascota?</p>
                <br>

                <ul class="puntos-encuesta pregunta">
                                    <textarea class="algo-mas-cc" name="PCC2" maxlength="250" id="fe590"></textarea>

                </ul>

            </div>


      </div>

    </div>
</section>


<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<section class="contenedor4">
    <div class="container-fluid f-white">

      <div class="row">

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">


                <ul class="puntos-encuesta pregunta">

                <p class="rojo planes"> Reprogramar agenda</p>
                <br>
                                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>

                 <h3 class="muchas-gracias-cc">&iexcl;Muchas gracias por tu opini&oacute;n!</h3>

                <input class="boton-rojo-cc enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">





                </ul>

            </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </section>



 <script>
        $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker();
    </script>


<script type='text/javascript'><!--//
var timerId = null, timeout = 5;
//--></script>

<script type='text/javascript'><!--//
function WaitUntilCustomerGUIDIsRetrieved() {
if (!!(timerId)) {
    if (timeout == 0) {
return;
}
if (typeof this.GetElqCustomerGUID === 'function') {
        document.forms["EncuestaCallCenter"].elements["elqCustomerGUID"].value = GetElqCustomerGUID();
return;
}
timeout -= 1;
}
timerId = setTimeout("WaitUntilCustomerGUIDIsRetrieved()", 500);
return;
}
window.onload = WaitUntilCustomerGUIDIsRetrieved;
_elqQ.push(['elqGetCustomerGUID']);
//--></script>


</form>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que los datos que enviar no esten vacios puedes utilizar el required

```
<input type="date" id="Fecha" name="Fecha" required"/>
```

si esto pones en todos los input te salga un mensaje si esta vacios que se tiene que llenar esos datos

Ahora la fecha y hora actual yo utilizo esto en mi javascript

```
function ObtenerFechaHora(){
  var f = new Date();
  const date = new Date(f.getTime() - f.getTimezoneOffset() * 60 * 1000);
  var fecha_actual = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
  var hora_actual = date..toISOString().slice(11, 16).split(":",1)) + 1 + ":00";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<section class="contenedor4">
    <div class="container-fluid f-white">

      <div class="row">

           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">

                
                <ul class="puntos-encuesta pregunta">
                                   
                <p class="rojo planes"> Reprogramar agenda</p>
                <br>
                                    <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                  
                 <h3 class="muchas-gracias-cc">&iexcl;Muchas gracias por tu opini&oacute;n!</h3>

                <input class="boton-rojo-cc enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">
             
             
             
             

                </ul>

            </div>


      </div>

    </div>
  </section>



 <script>
        $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker();

        1. instala moment y Jquery.
        2. coloca tus input dentro de una etiqueta form.
        3. colocale un atributo name y id a cada input del formulario y required


       prueba esto y me avisas de algun problema.

        $("form").submit(function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
           const data = $("form").serialize();
           save() {
             // dentro de este if puedes colocar otras condiciones
             if(moment(data.fecha).isAfter(moment())) {

                 $.Ajax({
                   method: 'POST',
                   data: data,
                   url: 'http://tuRutaAlServidor',
                   success: function(result){
                      console.log('aquí se maneja la respuesta del servidor 
                      cuando no hubo error');
                   }
                 });
             } else {
                console.log('llene los campos obligatorios del formulario');
             }
          });


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar los required que te han comentado o puedes usar una función personalizada para validar el formulario antes de mandarlo. Para hacer eso, quítale el type="submit" al botón de Enviar y en vez de eso ponle un onclick que apunte a la función con la que vas a validar los campos. Si todas las condiciones que necesitas se cumplen, llamas al submit desde el propio formulario.

```
<div class="boton-rojo-cc enviar" onclick={validateForm} value="Enviar respuestas" id="fe583">
```

```
function validateForm() {
  if(lasCondicionesQueSean){
    document.querySelector("#form63").submit();
  }
  else{
    alert("Revisa el formulario")
  }
}
```